# How to display UIActionSheet on the Bottom of ipad same as iphone in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiactionsheet

I am new to `iOS` and I am facing a problem regarding `UIActionSheet`.

My code is like this

```
-(IBAction)picimgbtnClick:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Profile Photo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:
                            @"Gallery",
                            @"Camera",
                            @"Remove Photo",
                            nil];


    popup.tag = 1;
    [popup showInView:self.view];
}
```

This works perfectly on iPhone but when I run this on an iPad, the `UIActionSheet` appears in the middle (see image below) and also **doesn't show a cancel button**:

[image]

On iPhone, it appears like this:

[image]

Comment: it's a default behaviour for ipad . you can not chage it

Comment: you can use UIPopoverController.

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/uiactionsheet-uipopovercontroller-tutorial/ read this link

Comment: @balkaran But it is showing on button not on buttom.

Answer (score 5):

At first `UIActionSheet` is now deprecated so use latest code for it.

```
- (IBAction)capture:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Camera" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

        // Code for Cam
    }]];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Gallery" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

        //Code for Gallery
    }]];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Remove Photo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

        //Code for removing photo
    }]];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

    }]];
    [alert setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alert popoverPresentationController];
    popPresenter.sourceView = sender;
    popPresenter.sourceRect = sender.bounds; // You can set position of popover
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

And as @balkaran singh said it's a default behaviour for ipad . you can not change it. If you want then you concrete your custom class and by animation you can get exact UI what you need.

Comment: Note-able: `#define IS_DEVICE_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`

Answer (score 0):

Here methods `showInView` and `showFromRect` makes differences where on `iPhone` you will get the `cancel` option using `showInView` method but the same function you use in iPad you will not get.

Here are some methods you can customize your `actionSheet` origin see below image:

[image]

`UIActionSheet's showFromRect:inView:animated:` method is only supposed to be used on `iPad`. Its behavior on `iPhone` is undefined.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @vibhav But I am not abel to set it width. it shows the same width always

Comment: you dont need to set the width above  is just a explanation to use `showFromRect` method or [you can set this within few minutes see this](https://www.appcoda.com/uiactionsheet-uipopovercontroller-tutorial/)

Comment: @vibhav I need to display it same as iphone.

Comment: you cant displays same as like `iPhone` by default just create custom sheet using above link then you can do that ..

Answer (score -2):

You cannot show an action sheet from the bottom on the iPad, what you can do is show an alert.

The `UIActionSheet` class in deprecated since iOS 8, and should no longer be used. Instead you should make use of the `UIAlertController`. This works almost the same way:

```
UIAlertController *alert =
    [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Profile Photo"
                                        message:@"Select method of input"
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Gallery"
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^void (UIAlertAction *action) {
                                            NSLog(@"Clicked Gallery");
                                        }]];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Camera"
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^void (UIAlertAction *action) {
                                            NSLog(@"Clicked Camera");
                                        }]];
[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Remove Photo"
                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^void (UIAlertAction *action) {
                                            NSLog(@"Clicked Remove Photo");
                                        }]];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This will present the options as an alert, which is analogous to the alert sheet on the iPhone:

[image: Image of the alert]

There is no supported way of showing it the exact same way (from the bottom) as on the iPhone. If you think about it, it is very hard to reach the bottom of the iPad from many ways of holding it. The center makes much more sense.

Comment: u will get crash if does not set sourceRect/sourceView